# qbo3 Dropdown with multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html-select, qbo3

I have a QBO3 task that includes a dropdown list configured to make an API call with several possible parameters.

The API call is:

```
Process/DatawarehouseQuery?Field1=Foo&Field2=Bar
```

The fields on the task include:

- DWDropdown: a dropdown list that should render the results of the DatawarehouseQuery api call
- Field1: an input that users can enter data into
- Field2: an input that users can enter data into

I have configured an `onchange` event handler for the `Field1` as follows:

```js
document.id('DWDropdown').retrieve('qbo.Dropdown').refresh({'Field1', this.value});
```

and similarly for `Field2`:

```js
document.id('DWDropdown').retrieve('qbo.Dropdown').refresh({'Field2', this.value});
```

When a user triggers the `Field1.onchange` event, the API call made is:

```
Process/DatawarehouseQuery?Field1=Foo
```

When a user triggers the `Field2.onchange` event, the API call made is:

```
Process/DatawarehouseQuery?Field2=Bar
```

How do I configure the task to pass both `Field1` and `Field2` to the API call?

Answer (score 0):

The `qbo3.Dropdown` behavior's `refresh` method requires all the data needed for the api call:

> carriage returns added for clarity; the doubling of {{ and }} is an artifact of QBO's Task GUI designer.

```js
document.id('DWDropdown').retrieve('qbo.Dropdown').refresh({{
  'Field1': document.id('Field1').value,
  'Field2': document.id('Field2').value
}});
```

As the number of fields grow, maintaining these `onchange` handlers can become unwieldy. As an alternative, you can create a custom function in the `Javascript` panel of the task, and reference that function from each of your onchange handlers:

[image: Task GUI designer Javascript tab]

```js
function refreshDWDropdown()
{
  document.id('DWDropdown').retrieve('qbo.Dropdown').refresh({
    'Field1': document.id('Field1').value,
    'Field2': document.id('Field2').value
  });
}
```

and then your `onchange` handler becomes:

```js
refreshDWDropdown();
```

---

When troubleshooting dropdown lists (or any other [qbo3 behaviors](https://github.com/quandis/qbo3-Documentation/wiki/behaviors)), consider using the [Chrome debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) and [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).

Specifically, you can play with a dropdown list from the debugger console along these lines:

```
var dd = document.id('DWDropdown').retrieve('qbo.Dropdown');
dd.options; // this will show you the options, including url and data, used by the dropdown
dd.refresh({'Field1': 'Foo', 'Field2': 'Bar'}); // this will trigger the refresh directly
dd.refresh({'Field1': document.id('Field1').value}); // mimic your existing onchange code
dd.refresh({'Field1': document.id('Field1').value, 'Field2': document.id('Field2').value}); // mimic the recommend onchange code
refreshDWDropdown(); // call your function directly
```